# Appending string to destination to create new directory

Tags: java, file, directory

Hello I am attempting to append some variables to a directory to create a new sub directory within the directory I am in but I am not sure how to do this, I know that .mkdir() allows me to create a new directory but I am not sure how I could append the variables and then create the new directory, here is my attempt so far:
package movefile;

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class MoveFile
{
static String newfile;


public static void main(String[] args)
{   
    File srcFolder = new File("/Users/francis/Desktop/folder1");
    File destFolder = new File("/Users/francis/Desktop/folder2");
    //make sure source exists
    if(!srcFolder.exists()){

       System.out.println("Directory does not exist.");
       //just exit
       System.exit(0);
    }else{      
       try{
        copyFolder (srcFolder,destFolder);
       }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        //error, just exit
            System.exit(0);
       }
    }       
    System.out.println("Done");
}

 public static void copyFolder(File src, File dest)
    throws IOException{

        if(src.isDirectory()){

        //if directory not exists, create it
        if(!dest.exists()){
           dest.mkdir();
           System.out.println("Directory copied from " 
                          + src + "  to " + dest);
        }
        //list all the directory contents
        String files[] = src.list();
            FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter()
    {
        @Override public boolean accept(File dir, String name)
    {
    return name.endsWith(".pdf");
    }
    };
        for (String file : files) {
           //construct the src and dest file structure
           File srcFile = new File(src, file); //needed for moving

              //third attempt  
                File f = null;
                File f1 = null;
                String vendor;
                String orderno;
                String desc;
                String v, v1, p;
                boolean bool = false;

                try {
                    f = new File("/Users/francis/Desktop/folder1/1234567898.pdf");
                    f1 = new File("/Users/francis/Desktop/folder2/");

                    v = f.getName();
                    v1 = f1.getName();

                    v = v.length() > 9 ? v.substring(0,8) : v;

                    p = "c3269";

                    vendor = "VendorName";

                    v = "file_" + p + " - " + v + ".pdf";

                    File destFile = new File(dest, v);    //get dest and insert (append) project number so it creates new folder
                    copyFolder(srcFile,destFile);

                   File appendProject = new File("/Users/francis/Desktop/folder2/");

                   boolean successfull = appendProject.mkdir();

                    if (successfull)
                    {
                        System.out.println("New directory was created:");
                    }
                    else
                        System.out.println("Failed to create new directory");

                    bool = f.exists();

                    if(bool)
                    {
                        System.out.println("File name:" + v);
                    }
                    bool = f1.exists();
                    if (bool)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Folder name:" + v1);
                    }    
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



            }
    }else{
        //if file, then copy it
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dest); 

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            int length;
            //copy the file content in bytes 
            while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0){
               out.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            in.close();
            out.close();
            System.out.println("File copied from " + src + " to " + dest);
    }
   }   
  }
```

At the moment this is checking the folder for .pdf files appending P and V values to the name, trimming the string to 8 characters and moving the files into a new folder but I desire them to be moved and it creates new directory based on the project number which is located inside of the variable p.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks a bunch!

Comment: Please start with formatting your code in order to reduce misunderstandings. Also add the missing variables and methods or add a description if a method is too large, e.g. what are `srcFile`, `dest` etc. and what is `copyFolder(srcFile,destFile);` meant to do?

Comment: The srcFile declares the source file from which the items are to be copied from, the dest is the destination file as to where these items will be copied too and copy folder is the name of my class, it's for moving purposes but I didn't want to paste my whole programs source code in

Comment: Add it to your post please, having to combine information in the question and in comments only makes it harder.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to copy file `File srcFile` to folder `File destDir` you could do the following:

```
if( !destDir.exists() ) {
  //create destDir and all missing parent folders
  destDir.mkdirs(); //For simplicity I'll leave out the success checks, don't forget them in your code
}

String destFilename = srcFile.getName(); //adapt according to your needs
File destFile = new File( destDir, destFilename );

//You'd need to either implement that or use a library like Apache Commons IO
copy( srcFile, destFile );
```

If you want to create a directory from the filename first, do something like this:

```
String destSubDirName = makeDirName( destFilename ); //whatever you need to do here
File destSubDir = new File( destDir, destSubDirName );
destSubDir.mkdirs(); //again don't forget the checks

File destFile = new File (destSubDir, destFilename );

copy( srcFile, destFile );
```

Comment: The second example looks sort of like what I am attempting to do, I'm attempting to grab whatever is contained in dest and insert/append the project number which is stored inside of the variable p to the directory so that it creates a new folder within the directory for this

Comment: @DavidThomlinson you _might_ consider providing more information, e.g.  how you tried it and what happened (e.g. in what way didn't it work). Can you update your question and add the relevant part of your code? And did you debug to see where it starts to go wrong?